# Toggle arrow issue react hooks

Tags: reactjs

can you help me with the following issue: I have a react Hooks component and I want to toggle arrow when I click on the span, it works but only once, when I click it again it doesn't work no more, I don't understand why? Here is my component:

```
const ViewDetails = () => {
  const [ expanded, setIsExpanded ] = useState(false)

  const info = expanded ? 'Hide details' : 'View details';

  return (
  <div className={styles.viewDetails}>
    <span 
    className={ expanded ? styles.expanded : undefined }
    onClick={() => !setIsExpanded(true)}
    >
      <DownArrow />
    </span>
  <span className={styles.viewDetails}>{info}</span>
  </div>
  )};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the span onClick, try writing:

```js
onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!expanded)}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the previous state value to toggle `expanded`. The current function `{() => !setIsExpanded(true)}` will return `true` for all cases.

The solution.

```
const toggle = () => setIsExpanded((val) => !val);

return (
  <div className={styles.viewDetails}>
    <span 
    className={ expanded ? styles.expanded : undefined }
    onClick={toggle}
    >
      <DownArrow />
    </span>
  <span className={styles.viewDetails}>{info}</span>
  </div>
  )};
```

Codesandbox example -- [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hill-o06zw?file=/src/App.js)